# Scrolling Page Div Over Imagebutton also Scrolling down

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I created Div Over Image button css style  postion is absolute
when i scroll the pages the div also scrolling down 
how can i fix the dive over image button

```
#DamageDiv {
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;/* heighest z-index show on top */
```

}

```
function DrawImage(e) {
        var evt  = e || window.event; // compliant with ie6 
        var posX = evt.clientX;
        var posY = evt.clientY;
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = DamageType;
        iDiv.style.top = posY + "px";
        iDiv.style.left = posX + "px";
        iDiv.style.width = "20px";
        iDiv.style.height = "20px";
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position:absolute` from your CSS - this makes the div stay in the same place on the screen when you scroll.

Read here:
[Difference between style = "position:absolute" and style = "position:relative"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457790/difference-between-style-positionabsolute-and-style-positionrelative)

Comment: if i remove absolute div drawn under the image button not over the button

Comment: You didn't give the CSS or HTML of the page, so it's quite hard to tell what is the button and what is the image, but a bit of tinkering with HTML and CSS and you'll be able to do that without `position:absolute`