# I CANNOT get this div to close... Why?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a portfolio website for myself (just for fun), and I have gotten a nav bar developed that I really like. Now, I cannot seem to close the overall nav bar div parent, and every div that I insert seems to appear inside the nav bar div as a child, even though I've checked about 20 times to make sure everything is closed. Did I do something in my CSS that is forcing it to stay open and create more children?

If you look in the HTML code, the picture div keeps appearing inside my nav bar. It's extremely frustrating.

```
<DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>

    <title>Jeff Lester | Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="nav">

        <div class="buttons">

            <div class="programming">
                <p><a href="#">Programming</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="cinematography">
                <p><a href="#">Cinematography</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="photography">
                <p><a href="#">Photography</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="skills">
                <p><a href="#">Skills</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="bio">
                <p><a href="#">Bio</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="jeff_lester">
                <p><a href="#">Jeff Lester</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="picture"><p>Picture</p></div>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('retina_wood_@2X.png')
}

/* Navigation Bar */

.nav {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 4px solid #6E94E6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    opacity: 0.80;
}

.nav a {
    color: #858585;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #303030;
}

/* Approx. 62% of page */
.nav .buttons {
    width: 1202px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav .buttons .programming {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    float: right;
}

.nav .buttons .cinematography {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    float: right;
}

.nav .buttons .photography {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    float: right;
}

.nav .buttons .Skills {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    float: right;
}

.nav .buttons .bio {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    float: right;
}

.nav .buttons .jeff_lester {
    background-color: #6E94E6;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    margin-right: 400px;
    float: right;
}

.nav .buttons .jeff_lester a {
    color: #F5F5F5;
}

.nav .buttons .jeff_lester a:hover {
    color: #303030;
}
```

Comment: That really makes no sense. Lots of fixed navbars have I seen but I am seeing this behaviour for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, it's very bizarre. I made another website with a nav bar that was fixed and it caused no problems. I cannot seem to find a diagnosis! For now, I'm just building the site with it un-fixed, and I'll figure it out later. Hope it doesn't come back to haunt me!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the .nav element is `position:fixed`. Changed to `position:relative` and done

here  is fixed

http://jsbin.com/fokunixa/1/edit

Update:

to make the .nav fixed without affecting the others element(in this case .picture) you have to  set  the .picture relative and give some margin from top.

```
.picture{
  position:relative;
  top:20px;

}
```

[Here the example.](http://jsbin.com/fokunixa/3/edit)

There are some great post that talk about positioning:

[Difference between style = "position:absolute" and style = "position:relative"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457790/difference-between-style-positionabsolute-and-style-positionrelative)

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: I wanted my nav bar to be stationary on the screen while scrolling down. Is there another way I can do this without the position:fixed tag? Edit: This did fix the problem, but now my nav bar won't stay fixed while scrolling!

Comment: If he adds any elements on top .picture, again he need to add padding for that.. Instead adding padding to the body{}

Comment: @user3624485 I have mentioned that workaround in my answer below

Comment: @mohamedrias I gave my answer based on this request(.picture element in this case) if he wants a general fix, he must ask them

Comment: @Misters Yes, I agree to your point. I feel its always better to give a future proof solution as i dont want him to ask another question when he adds extra element above .picture :)

Comment: Realy? You honestly thought that `.picture` was the only thing that was going to be under his `.nav`? Of course he wants a general fix, not just a patch! And then you decided to go for `position: relative` in stead of just adding some `margin-top`? You are not developing for me any time soon...

Answer (score 0):

First option: Remove `position: fixed;` from the `.nav`

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vexoqira/2/edit)

```
   .nav {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        height: 75px;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 70px;
        border-top: 4px solid #6E94E6;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
```

If you really want your `.nav` to be fixed while scrolling the page, then

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lexobesa/1/edit)

1. Add padding to your body

> ```
>  body {
>         background-image: url('retina_wood_@2X.png');
>         padding-top: 80px;
>      }
> ```

1. Add `top:0` in `.nav`

> ```
> .nav {
>                     background-color: #F5F5F5;
>                     height: 75px;
>                     width: 100%;
>                     position: fixed;
>                     line-height: 70px;
>                     border-top: 4px solid #6E94E6;
>                     border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
>                     opacity: 0.80;
>                     top: 0;
>                 }
> ```

Comment: @PeterVR I wanted to give a future proof solution. The answer by Misters gives temporary solution as he adds top to .picture. If the OP adds any elements above .picture then he need to add top for that as well. So i have added padding to body itself

Comment: exactly. It is what I did in my answer as well, be it with margin-top, but with the same goal. I really don't get the downvotes?... You got a +1 from me!

Comment: btw, if you want your answer to be really perfect, you should remove the `px` after the 0. 0 is just 0 and requires no unit... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the postion fixed if you want that effect. You need to take into account however that *fixed positioned elements are lifted out of the document flow*. That is why your 'picture' is not getting pushed down to the postion you would expect it to be and it appears to be inside your nav.

This can easily be solved by **adding a `margin-top` to your body that equals the height of your fixed header**, and **setting the `top` value of your header to 0**.

I went ahead and copied your code to a fiddle and added my suggestions:
http://jsfiddle.net/uHFv4/

**Off topic:** just because I can't help it, I know that this is not codereview, but your markup is quite horrible. You navigation is a list of links and should look something like:

```
   <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="programming">
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
            </li>
            ...
```

And in your css, you write all the styles for each button, while most often they are all the same except for the width. I sense some room for improvement there...

Answer (score 0):

When you using floats, they change the layout of the page. the document dosen't render a height for them. In the picture class you should write clear:both; to clear the floats and change the position of the nav to position relative as answered above. Like this:

```
.nav {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 4px solid #6E94E6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    opacity: 0.80;

}

.picture{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;

}
```

If you want to keep your header as position fixed then you can specify that it stays at the top of the document with top: 0px; and then give the picture class a top margin of 70px or so, i.e the height of the nav. like this:

```
.nav {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;

    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 4px solid #6E94E6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    opacity: 0.80;

}

.picture{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 70px;


}
```

I've tested both of these and they work :) Good luck :)

Comment: Instead of adding margin-top to picture, try adding it to the body. Because if the user adds any DOM above .picture , then he again need to add margin-top on that as well. So let the answer be generic &  future proof.

Comment: Yes i see what you mean :)