# Why does position: relative make the height to zero?

Tags: html, css

So I am not a web developer and have very little experience with html and css so this might sound dumb:

But I saw code from my co worker who set a `section` to `position:relative` and the child element (an `h1` in this case) to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width:100%` and somehow the `h1` took the entire height and width of the parent which was the `section`.

I tried reproducing it below but it was not possible. Seems like the h1 has a height of zero since the border is not surrounding it. Is there something wrong with the code below?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .main {
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
    }

    h1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="main">
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the `position: relative` that is causing the problem but the `position: absolute` set on the `h1`. 
If the parent container having the absolutely positioned child element doesn't have an explicit width and height set, it will collapse. This is because absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document. 
In order to solve your problem, you can explicitly set height/width on your `.main`.

Comment: Ah ok, this is what I wanted to know. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: Also when you say `If the parent container having the absolutely positioned child element doesn't have an explicit width and height set, it will collapse.` Are you saying the parent component will collapse to zero or the child element?

Comment: The parent component will collapse if it has only absolutely positioned children, with no height/width set.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;height:0;width: 100%;` this css to `h1` class and your problem is solved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .main {
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
    }
    h1 {        
        border: 1px solid black;        
    }
</style>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="main">
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why a little bit more?

Comment: Please check this URL for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457790/difference-between-style-positionabsolute-and-style-positionrelative  . If you have still doubt then you can ask me.