# Add to Cart Button not showing next to product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have one weird issue with add to cart button into product archives page. When i open some product like [here](http://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/product-category/midi-loops/construction-kits/)

then i dont see "Add to Cart" button, but if i check in debugger i  see that in code add to cart link exist.. This is CSS class for selected element:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .price {
color: #FFF;
display: block;
font-weight: 300;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

and code from Inspect Element:

[image]

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/digital-products/product-category/midi-
loops/construction-kits/?add-to-cart=1850" data-quantity="1" data-
product_id="1850" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple 
add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Přida do košíku</a>
```

can someone to help me , or give me some tip how to resolve?

**EDIT**: When i inseert this CSS button is showing but float too big into page:

```
#layout .woocommerce a.button, .woocommerce-page a.button, .woocommerce button.button, .woocommerce-page button.button, .woocommerce input.button, .woocommerce-page input.button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit, .woocommerce-page #respond input#submit, .woocommerce #content input.button, .woocommerce-page #content input.button {
display:inherit;
}
```

Comment: add_to_cart_button has `absolute` value. Please check the closest parent element which has `relative` property. That might be the reason.

Comment: I checked but cant find near object with relative property.

Comment: You can check it by removing the `absolute` value or just add `position: relative` to products or product class.

Comment: Does add_to_cart_button have an `z-index` value?

Comment: I dont know really.

Comment: If you haven't set up any relative parent element, your absolute button will be placed 10px from top and left side of the browser. You may want to read here to learn more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457790/difference-between-style-positionabsolute-and-style-positionrelative

Comment: I didnt haved set nothing.. Its from Remix theme and Woocommerce.

Comment: Can't access your link. Its with a coming soon

Comment: Anyone? Still cant resolve this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
display: inline-block;
opacity: 1;
```