# My Image is not taking up full width of page

Tags: html, css

For some reason my image is not taking up the entire width of page. I commented out my entire site.css file besides the #ResterauntImage code.

Picture Below :

[image]

```css
#ResterauntImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0px;

    background-image: url("");
    overflow: hidden;
    /*-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);*/
    /*-webkit-filter: sepia(100%);*/
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
  
  
  <img id="ResterauntImage"class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="http://www.gatesgardencentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gn043-MED-WIDE.jpg" />
```

Comment: did u put your image image inside container?

Comment: It's working for me - in both Chrome and Firefox.

Some things:

Add a space between `id="ResterauntImage"` and `class="img-fluid"`.

You're setting `position` to `absolute` and you're then overriding it immediately with `relative`.

`<img/>` tags shouldn't really have background images (it's valid CSS, but why?).

What is it that you are trying to achieve? Is this image supposed to cover the entirety of the window?

Comment: You have `position: absolute` which totally depends on its parent with `position:relative`. So you might want to check width you are getting of parent first having *`position: relative`*. If that is wide enough, your image must also have it.

Comment: @divy3993 `position:absolute;` is actually overridden by `position: relative;` in the same selector

Comment: @James, Oh yeah! that's right. I didn't noticed that.

Comment: I took it out and it still doesnt change

Comment: Perhaps bootstrap is messing with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed height of the image and it's working perfectly. The image now has 100% width. If you specify a `width:100%` there is no need to specify a height of an image as the browser will calculate it based on the ratio of the image (the default value for height is auto).

I removed some other tags like `background-image`, `background size`, `padding` and `position:relative` as you already have `position:absolute` in your code. I left only required code to make your image with 100% width.

I hope this solves the problem. I checked and in working on my page.

**Here is the code:**

```css
#ResterauntImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img id="ResterauntImage"class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="http://www.gatesgardencentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gn043-MED-WIDE.jpg" />
```

Comment: doesnt help, Still not full width

Comment: Run the code snippet. It takes 100% of the width of the screen. If it doesnt on your page it means you have conflict with other css code.

Comment: worked for me. I had earlier set `width` attribute to `inherit`. Changing it to `100%` worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you were specifying position twice, once as `position: absolute` and that's what it should be and once as `position: relative`, which is not what you want.
For more information and difference between `postion: absolute` and `position:relative` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457790/difference-between-style-positionabsolute-and-style-positionrelative) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

```css
#ResterauntImage {
    position: absolute;
   left: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* this is false! position: relative;*/
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0px;

    background-image: url("");
    overflow: hidden;
    /*-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);*/
    /*-webkit-filter: sepia(100%);*/
   -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
  
  
  <img id="ResterauntImage"class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="http://www.gatesgardencentre.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gn043-MED-WIDE.jpg" />
```