# Vertical alignment not taking margins into account

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center content in a fixed-height `<div>`.

I'm using the technique of `top:50%` and `transform:translateY(-50%)` to do this, but I cannot understand why the `margin` of the child elements are not being taken into account, but the `padding` is.

If you run the snippet below, you can see the contents of the left box (where the `<p>` elements have browser default margins) has a lower vertical alignment than the right box (where the `<p>` elements have had the margins removed and replaced with `padding`) which sits perfectly in the center.

**Why are the margins causing this issue, but the padding isn't?**

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin-right:5%;
  width:45%;
  float:left;
}
.content {
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  background-color:cyan;
}
.no_p_margin p {
  margin:0;
  padding:8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="content no_p_margin">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin collapsing .. add overflow:auto and both example will be fine

Comment: you should also note the initial position of your element and that top will move the element from that positon not the top of the container element (I am adding another duplicate)

Comment: to illustrate what is happening : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42720659/8620333

Comment: Try overflow:hidden to content and it will take whole height