# How is working z-index on relative parent and relative childs?

Tags: html, css, position, frontend, z-index

How does z-index really work?

```html
 <div class="picture">
      <img src="img/japan1.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/japan2.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/japan3.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/japan4.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/japan5.png" alt="">
  </div>
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picture{

    background-color:rgb(189, 178, 155);
    height: 540px;
    width:960px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-1;


}
img
{
    width:960px;
    height:540px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;

}


img:nth-child(1){

    top:50px;
    z-index:2;

}
img:nth-child(2){

    top:125px;
    z-index:10;

}
 img:nth-child(3){
    top:186px;
    z-index:6;
 }
```

i expected z-index will work, but i can see only see first child and background color on the screen. What is happening? With position absolute on img its working well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5DMS.png)

Comment: you need position:absolute not relative for the image (in your case everything is overflowing and only the first one is within the parent element

Comment: If i correctly understand : relative parent cannot be contener for relative childs, but can be for absolute childs? i mean positioning in reference to parent.

Comment: no they can, what you are missing is the meaning of position:relative which will consider the intial place of the element as the reference unlike the position:absolute and here you need to stack image so you need position:absolute (here is a good answer to illustrate https://stackoverflow.com/a/42720659/8620333 )