# Make the child height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `section` with a `min-height` css of `100%`. The child is a div with `height: 100%;`. But the child div does not occupy the whole parent `section`

What I'm trying to achieve is the child will occupy the space.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="content">
    HEY!
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Replace `min-height` with `height` in `.container`.

Comment: try it .content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}

Comment: I have to use `min-height` there are other child elements. I just want the `.content` to be have the same height with the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `position:absolute` to the child element.

If you want the parent element to be relative then add `position:relative` to parent element.

Relative Position:
A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position.

To know more about relative and absolute position visit:[Difference between style = "position:absolute" and style = "position:relative"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457790/difference-between-style-positionabsolute-and-style-positionrelative)

```css
     html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    div {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      color:white;   
      position: absolute;   
      background-color: blue;   
    }
```

```html
  <section class="container">    
      <div class="content">    
        HEY!   
      </div>   
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
#child1 { 
  background-color: blue; 
}

#child2 { 
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="content" id="child1">
    HEY Child 1 See Child 2 down!
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="child2">
    HEY Child 2!
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have to use min-height there are other child element. I just want the .content to be have the same height with the window

Answer (score 0):

> You should try this :

Just add

```
position: absolute;
```

in child css class.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;  
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="content">
    HEY!
  </div>
</section>
```